# Automatic DNS registration only for domain computer

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, dhcp

I have a windows domain with a win server 2012 domain controller with dns service installed.
In the DNS server there is the automatic DNS registration, is it possible to limit these registration only for domain machines? Now in my dns I can found anything... printers, mobile devices, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
To avoid this problem perform the following 3 steps (It is important that you follow all the steps to avoid the issue).

 1. Under Network Connections Properties: On the Unwanted NIC TCP/IP
    Properties -> Advanced -> DNS - > Uncheck "Register this connections
    Address in DNS"

 2. Open the DNS server console:  highlight the server on the left pane
        Action-> Properties and on the "Interfaces" tab select "listen on
        only the following IP addresses". Remove unwanted IP address from
        the list

 3. On the Zone properties, select Name server tab. Along with FQDN of
        the DC, you will see the IP address associated with the DC. Remove
        unwanted IP address if it is listed.


After performing this delete the existing unwanted Host A record of the DC.
```

Source : http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2023004

Comment: I'm a bit confused... I want to remove dns names of devices out of domain, not by ip address or subnet. I may have some domain ip in the same ip range than printers ip. Is it possible?

Comment: Oh my bad, I hope MBu satisfied you. You can still organize your network by filtering mac addresses, making a range for printers, phones etc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are also running DHCP Server service on a Windows Server. Go to DNS tab in the DHCP scope properties and clear "Dynamically update DNS A and PTR records for DHCP clients that do not request updates" checkbox.

Comment: Ok but clearing this flag, my domain computers will register and update their dns records? Thanks

Comment: Assuming you do not have any pre-Windows 2000 machines, your clients either register themselves on their own or are handled by the first flag.